# Django tutorial NoReverseMatch error

Tags: django, django-2.0

I was following the tutorial for Django, however, I encounter an error when I reach part 5.

```
NoReverseMatch at /polls/ 
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']

Request Method: GET 
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/ 
Django Version: 2.0.2 
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch 
Exception Value:     Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']

Error during template rendering
In template /media/shawn/New Volume/tests/django/mysite/polls/templates/polls/index.html, error at line 5
<li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
```

polls/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

polls/template/polls/index.html:

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}" />

<li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
```

polls/views.py:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic

from .models import Choice, Question


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Return the last five published questions (not including those set to be
        published in the future).
        """
        return Question.objects.filter(
            pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
        ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Excludes any questions that aren't published yet.
        """
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'


def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

Based on the error it seems to be due to polls/index.html. However, I don't really understand what it means.

Please let me know how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link should be wrapped in a for-loop:

```
{% for question in latest_question_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, not sure why the tutorial miss this part.

Comment: The tutorial does include the loop. Either you didn’t add it to begin with, or you removed it when you changed the link to use the url tag.